# Add entity relationship to EF Core scaffolded entity when database cannot be changed - and retaining the addition on rescaffold

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I am using a database-first approach to a third party database that I cannot change. The database has two tables that should have a constraint defining their primary/foreign key relationship. The constraint is missing so the entities generated do not have the relationship. Is it possible to add the entity relationships to the scaffolded entities without losing my additions if I need to scaffold again (due to an upgrade etc)?

I've thought about creating a custom partial class file extending the existing entity but this will not work if the existing entity already has a constructor. I need a constructor to instantiate a `HashSet<T>` of the other side of the relationship. I've also thought about using inheritance but not sure if that will work well with the existing entity.

**Update:** It seems like easiest solution may be to instead use linq join syntax and not provide the relationship in the entities but I'll leave the question up in case anyone has a good solution and a use case where it is beneficial.